# Classname.Variable use with Classname as a Variable

Tags: java, arrays, variables, classname

Depending on an Input given in another class, this class has to retrieve a variable from one of 4 classes in which that variable is to be found. Eg. if the input has been an `s` the variable this class is looking for is found in `Sumup.counter` whereas when the input has been an `a` the variable it needs, is to be found in `Abstract.counter` etc etc, in order to fill an Array. In one of these 4 different classes it has to pick up 5 different variables. So in order to avoid lots of extra programming I want to replace these class names `Sumup` and `Abstract` with a variable. So it has to look like anything like this `Variable.counter`, `Variable.part1` etc. In which Variable can be either `Sumup` or `Abstract` (or `Multiply` or `Divide`).

Anyone a suggestion how to do this?

```java
public class Erroranalysis {

    public static int[][] wrongcalculations = new int[5][Numberofcalculations.numcalc]; 

    static int runner = 0;
    static String routine;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        switch (kindofcalculation.choice) 
        {
         case "s":
             routine = "Sumup";
         break; 

         case "a":
             routine = "Abstract";
         break; 

         case "m":
             routine = "Multiply";
         break;     

         case "d":
             routine = "Divide";
         break; 
         }   

         if (routine.counter <= Numberofcalcluations.numcalc)
         {

             wrongcalculations[0][runner] = routine.counter;
             wrongcalculations[1][runner] = routine.part1;
             wrongcalculations[2][runner] = routine.part2;
             wrongcalculations[3][runner] = routine.result;
             wrongcalculations[4][runner] = routine.answer;


             runner++;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: 27 views, but apparently still nobody knows....

Comment: Maybe an extra tip...the 'routine' mentioned in the different 'cases'...refers to the 'routine' mentioned further down below in the 'if' section.

Comment: I'm confused, `routine` is a `String`, so why are you also accessing `part1`/`part2` etc on it? Those aren't even fields in the `String` class. Unless you've name a class `routine`... You should name all classes as `UpperCamelCase` so it's more readable. That said, include the variable declarations you use here (so how `routine.part1` and `kindofcalculation.choice` etc are defined).

Comment: Yes, `routine`
 is meant to be a variable to stand for a class name. So if the input `kindofcalculation.choice` is a (eg). `s` then a variable out of class name `Sumup` is need. That particular variable is a.o. called part1. So it want java it to understand that `wrongcalculations[1][runner] = routine.part1;` is read like `wrongcalculations[1][runner] = sumup.part1;` I indeed don't know how to declare `routine` so that it can be used as a variable that represents a class name.

Comment: "So it want java to understand (...)"....must be "So I want java to understand(...)" Sorry for that!!

Comment: After 58 I conclude that it is not possible in Java. Maybe a good suggestion to Java to develop the next version that makes this feature possible. !!!

Answer (score 0):

you can opt for a base abstract class and make an array of that class:

```
class Base{
  public int counter = 0;
}
class Sumup extends Base{
}
class Abstract extends Base{
}


public class Erroranalysis {

    public static int[][] wrongcalculations = new int[5][Numberofcalculations.numcalc]; 

    static int runner = 0;
    static Base routine;
    static Sumup sumup;
    static Abstract abs;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        sumup = new Sumup();
        abs = new Abstract();

        // possibly, this part won't be in main, but in some for loop of another method
        switch (kindofcalculation.choice) 
        {
         case "s":
             routine = sumup;

         case "a":
             routine = abs;

         }   

         if (routine.counter <= Numberofcalcluations.numcalc)
         {

             wrongcalculations[0][runner] = routine.counter;
             wrongcalculations[1][runner] = routine.part1;
             wrongcalculations[2][runner] = routine.part2;
             wrongcalculations[3][runner] = routine.result;
             wrongcalculations[4][runner] = routine.answer;

             runner++;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: wauw that sound pretty complicated but I'll give it a try..thanks!!

Comment: I tweaked it a little, please check. Also, please do give an upvote :)

Comment: Sorry, But I can't manage to implement your suggestion. You know, I am a beginner of Java and this seems too complicated. I had expected the solutions to be something like, that I had to use some operators in which between to put the variable. Something like: wrongcalculations[0][runner] = <routine>.counter; or, wrongcalculations[0][runner] = &routine&.counter; I was hoping for this simple solutions!! Or to declare routine as a Classname variable. Something like  static String Classname(routine);